Overlapping content issue with a background image
How can I put an image at the top of the page that fades when scrolling and the page content (main text) overlaps the picture as it fades.
I'm a beginner and I use Visual Studio Code. First of all, I don't have a lot of knowledge in coding as I just started this year to learn, second thing is that this project is a copy for school homework - the assignment is to take our favorite site and copy it without using inspect element for copy and paste.
This is the site I want to copy:
https://www.townandcountrymag.com/leisure/sporting/news/g2165/best-vintage-cars/
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var background = document.querySelector('.background-image');

    // Listen for scroll event
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        // Calculate opacity based on scroll position
        var opacity = 0.5 - (window.scrollY / window.innerHeight);


        // Set opacity to the background image
        background.style.opacity = opacity > 0 ? opacity : 0;
    });
});

 /* Reset and general styles */
body {
    font-family: 'Kumbh Sans', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent horizontal scrollbar */
}

* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* Background image */
.background-image {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('1954-mercedes-300sl-gullwing-a_1.jpg'); /* Replace 'your-background-image.jpg' with your image path */
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.5; /* Set initial opacity */
    z-index: -1; /* Behind other content */
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease; /* Add transition effect */
}

/* Navigation design */
.title {
    background: rgb(31, 31, 31);
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: -10px; /* Adjust margin */
}

.title_text {
    background-color: rgb(137, 218, 15);
    background-size: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

/* Main content section */
.content {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: -500px; /* Adjust margin */
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px; /* Adjust the max-width as needed */
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center; /* Center items vertically */
}

section h2 {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    font-size: 1.8rem; /* Increase font size */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

section img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px; /* Adjust the max-width as needed */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the image horizontally */
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

section p {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    font-size: 1.2rem; /* Increase font size */
    color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Footer */
footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Proiect - Claudio Negrea</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="background-image"></div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1><i class="title_text">SITE - PROIECTUL LA PCLP</i></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <section>
            <h2>Jaguar E-Type</h2>
            <img src="1968-jaguar-e-type_1.jpg" alt="Jaguar E-Type">
            <p>The 1960s Jaguar E-Type, famously praised by Enzo Ferrari as "the most beautiful car ever made," remains a classic sports car icon. With its impressive performance—reaching speeds of up to 150 mph—and superior braking capabilities for its time, it continues to capture the hearts of enthusiasts. Experience the thrill firsthand at the Jaguar Heritage Driving Experience program in Kenilworth, U.K., where you can spend a day driving these timeless classics.</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    <footer>
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <p>Email: Claudio@gmail.com</p>
            <p>Phone: 0719346413</p>
        <p>&copy; 2024 Your Company. All rights reserved.</p>
    </footer>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


The image on that example website isn't fading. There's a div over the top of it that has a linear gradient of transparent to white.

Use css sticky positioning on that background car image so that it will stay put in its place visible till some scrolling distance then once that is crossed it starts to behave normal

you have the site, you can look at all the files it uses, so replicate the effect, it might need some reading/puzzling
